# Where are nanomsg nng libraries installed

Tags: cmake, nanomsg

I am new to nanomsg and cmake. I installed the nanomsg using the documentation

```
 $ mkdir build
 $ cd build
 $ cmake -G Ninja ..
 $ ninja
 $ ninja test
 $ ninja install
```

I am not sure where are the packages installed. I see the headers in `/usr/include` and `cmake` directory in `/usr/lib64` directory.

```
 /usr/lib64/cmake/nng# ls
 nng-config.cmake  nng-config-noconfig.cmake
```

I am unable to compile my sample programs due to this confusion. Any help would be highly appreciated.